# How to solve runtime error "Access denied finding property"?

Tags: java, android, runtime-error

I'm working on a simple counter project, you press a button and the number displayed either gets +1 or -1. I'm getting a `run time error` indicating:

> E/libc: Access denied finding property "vendor.debug.egl.profiler"

Where does this error come from? And what can be done to fix it?

```
package com.example.mtglifecounter;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

Button counter1Up, counter1Down, counter2Up, counter2Down;
TextView lifeCount1, lifeCount2;


int life1 = 20;
int life2 = 20;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    setUI();

    counter1Up.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            life1 = life1+ 1;
            lifeCount1.setText(life1);
        }
    });

    counter1Down.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            life1 = life1 -1;
            lifeCount1.setText(life1);
        }
    });

    counter2Up.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            life2 = life2 + 1;
            lifeCount2.setText(life2);
        }
    });

    counter2Down.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            life2 = life2 - 1;
            lifeCount2.setText(life2);
        }
    });
}

public void setUI(){
    counter1Up = findViewById(R.id.counter1UpBTN);
    counter1Down = findViewById(R.id.counter1DownBTN);
    counter2Up = findViewById(R.id.counter2UpBTN);
    counter2Down = findViewById(R.id.counter2DownBTN);

    lifeCount1 = findViewById(R.id.counter1TV);
    lifeCount2 = findViewById(R.id.counter2TV);

    lifeCount1.setText("20");
    lifeCount2.setText("20");
}
}
```

and this is all that comes up in `Logcat`:

```
2019-01-21 21:12:49.524 22001-22049/com.example.mtglifecounter E/libc: Access denied finding property "vendor.debug.egl.profiler"
```

Answer (score 0):

> Where does this error come from?

Android SELinux (rules/config, which done by OEM)

> And what can be done to fix it?
> refer:

- offical doc

  - [Validating SELinux  |  Android Open Source Project](https://source.android.com/security/selinux/validate)
- other related posts

  - [8.3.8. Allowing Access: audit2allow Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6 | Red Hat Customer Portal](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/6/html/security-enhanced_linux/sect-security-enhanced_linux-fixing_problems-allowing_access_audit2allow)
  - [Android SELinux avc dennied权限问题解决方法_缥缈孤鸿影的专栏-CSDN博客_avc denied](https://blog.csdn.net/tung214/article/details/72734086)
  - [Android selinux 解决实例 - mojl - 博客园](https://www.cnblogs.com/mojl-cnblogs/p/11053174.html)

need to use `audit2allow` and other tools, **maybe** finnaly can fix it.

More detailed explanation can refer [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59533551/access-denied-finding-property-persist-vendor-log-tel-dbg/63259127#63259127)