# Access denied finding property "persist.vendor.log.tel_dbg"

Tags: android-studio

I am trying to display Json data extracted from open weather map api and find it in the logcat.After successful build and installation of the app.I am getting this error.The error is Access denied finding property "persist.vendor.log.tel_dbg"

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

EditText mEditText;
TextView mTextView;
String api="http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather? 
q=kolkata&appid=e8cd0e5f8d3ba1e87d108da87d9c0a94";
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    DownloadTask task=new DownloadTask();
    task.execute(api);
}
public class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String>
{
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
        String result="";
        URL url;
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection=null;
        try {
            url=new URL(urls[0]);
            urlConnection=(HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
            InputStream in=urlConnection.getInputStream();
            InputStreamReader reader=new InputStreamReader(in);
            int data=reader.read();
            while (data!=-1)
            {
                char current=(char)data;
                result+=current;
                data=reader.read();
            }

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return result;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        Log.i("Result",result);
      }
   }

}
```

[Image of Logcat](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E8bHg.jpg)

Answer (score 4):

## As show in screenshot:

[image: logcat avd deined]

before error log

`Access denied finding property "persist.vendor.log.tel_dbg"`

there is another warning:

`type=1400 audit(xxx): avc: denied { read } for xxx`

which is the reason for above error `Access denied finding property`

## Example to show the root cause of `Access denied finding property`

I encount similar error:

```sh
com.gsma.rcs W/com.gsma.rcs: type=1400 audit(0.0:526384): avc: denied { read } for name="u:object_r:vendor_displayfeature_prop:s0" dev="tmpfs" ino=16384 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app_25:s0:c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:vendor_displayfeature_prop:s0 tclass=file permissive=0
```

Exapnation:

- `Action`：**read**
- `Actor`=`scontext`=`source context`：**untrusted_app_25**
- `Object`=`tcontext`=`target context`：**vendor_displayfeature_prop**

  - Note：

    - corresponding later: `ro.vendor.df.effect.conflict`
    - `object_r`=`object read` ？
- `Result`=`tclass`=`target class`：**file**
- `permissive`=`permissive mode`：**0**

  - 0 permissive：not allow = denied
  - background：

    - selinux has two mode:

      - permissive mode
      - enforcing mode
    - during Android device booting, you can use kernel parameter to config mode:

      - `androidboot.selinux=permissive`
      - or
      - `androidboot.selinux=enforcing`

Translate to human readable words:

the **untrusted_app_25** want to **read** the **vendor_displayfeature_prop**, which type is **file**
but due to **NOT** permissive mode, Android SELinux denied (according to OEM built-in configuration of SELinux)

which cause the following output error log:

```sh
com.gsma.rcs E/libc: Access denied finding property "ro.vendor.df.effect.conflict"
```

## How to fix `avc: denied` error ?

refer official doc:

[Validating SELinux  |  Android Open Source Project](https://source.android.com/security/selinux/validate)

use `audit2allow` maybe can fix it.

Comment: Please share in easy words. Example would help

Comment: The screen shot is too shrunk to be readable to me.  Is there some "easy" way to correlate: `u:object_r:vendor_displayfeature_prop:s0` or some other part of the "causing" message with the original name string asked about `persist.vendor.log.tel_dbg` ?  I have a similar problem in an application I am working with but I can't tell how to correlate the single subsequent error message I am interested in with the very noisy avc messages above, most of which are not related.  I have over 50 "denied { find" for 1 E access denied error.